# How to query Google Analytics using Javascript

Tags: google-analytics

We're want to query Google Analytics remotely, to retrieve (and display) a list of most popular pages (in a certain period) on a website. The examples I've looked at, for querying Analytics using Javascript, seem to require an user/person to login. Is this correct? Is there a way of skipping this step, and querying Analtyics unattended?

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 0):

No. the data inside Google Analytics is potentially strategic and the tool doesn't provide non-logged in access at any time.

In order to do what you want the best approach is probably to query the data using your credentials on the server side and store the data on a database. Run that again every night or so.

Then you just query the database and generate the count to display on the frontend.

You don't want to do that on javascript because you would be exposing your credentials to anyone visiting your site to query all your Google Analytics data.

Comment: Thanks for replying, that is indeed what I am doing. I probably didn't explain it very well, but the problem I had was finding examples - Google's code mostly seems to demonstrate how to get individual users to authenticate using oAuth. This is actually for some node.js work, and eventually I found this:

https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-googleanalytics

which does what I want!

Comment: @toby1kenobi, people are looking for an answer to this question. May be you can post your own answer, so people know that the question has an answer.